# Memory Corruption error in Vector access

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, stdvector

I get a memory corruption error 'malloc(): memory corruption: 0x000000000234d4b0 ***'. My code is like below. I suspect that error is due to invalid memory access in the vector function. My code is as below.

```
bool compare_rect(const cv::Point3i &a, const cv::Point3i &b) {
  if (a.x > b.x) return true;
  if (a.y > b.y) return true;
  if (a.z > b.z) return true;
  return false;
}

std::vector<cv::Point3i> patches;
std::sort(patches.begin(), patches.end(), compare_rect);
cv::Point3i dpoint1 = patches.front(); 
int mean1 = dpoint1.x;
int cord1 = dpoint1.y;
int cord2 = dpoint1.z;
int cord3 =0; int cord5 =cord1;
int cord4 =0; int cord6 =cord2;
int it = 0;
for(int i=1; i < patches.size(); i++){
  cv::Point3i dpoint2 = patches[i];
  int mean2 = dpoint2.x; 
  cord3 = dpoint2.y;
  cord4 = dpoint2.z; 
  if (abs(cord4-cord6)>10){
    if (abs(cord3-cord5)>10){
      if(abs(mean2-mean1) > 5){
        cv::rectangle(display_obstacles, cv::Point(cord1, cord2), cv::Point(cord5, cord6), CV_RGB(0,255,0));
        cord1 = cord3;
        cord2 = cord4;
        it = it + 1;
      }
    }
  }
  if(i == (patches.size()-1)){
    cv::rectangle(display_obstacles, cv::Point(cord1, cord2), cv::Point(cord5, cord6), CV_RGB(0,255,0));
  }
  mean1 = mean2;
  cord5 = cord3;
  cord6 = cord4;
}
```

Can you help me identify the error ?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Run it through a debugger to find exactly where the problem is caused

Comment: Do you have a memory debugger like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org)? If not then find one and use it, those are very good att finding problems like that.

Comment: The code posted as is will not compile.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Your comparison doesn't satisfy the requirements for `std::sort` (`{0,0,1}` and `{1,0,0}` will both be "greater" than the other). This makes your code undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this fragment

```
std::vector<cv::Point3i> patches;
std::sort(patches.begin(), patches.end(), compare_rect);
cv::Point3i dpoint1 = patches.front();
int mean1 = dpoint1.x;
int cord1 = dpoint1.y;
int cord2 = dpoint1.z;
```

You declare `patches` as an empty vector.

You sort it but an empty vector, sorted, remain an empty vector.

`front()` of an empty vector give undefined effects.

And I suppose that accessing `dpoint1.x`, `dpoint.y` and `dpoint.z` doesn't help.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: This may or may not be the problem.  The OP needs to provide a MCVE to know for sure and they also have UB in their comparison function that may also cause this.

Comment: Actually I add Point3i types objects to the vector in early part of the code. Didn't share it because it will be too lengthy. Even the code complete all the loops prior to giving any memory corruption error.

Comment: I'm trying to categories similar disparities together in this code. I construct the v-disparity map and then calculate road surface and remove disparities corresponding to the road surface. Then I get obstacle only image. Then I divide the image into small patches and calculate mean. Now I'm trying to combine similar patches based on the mean, and the x, y coordinates. a.x = mean, a.y = x-coordinate, a.z=y-coordinate

Comment: @Hasi - if you share with us a code, we can find errors in that code, not in code that you don't share. I've found a false positive because you removed part of your code; are you sure that the error isn't in the code you didn't shared? Suggestion: prepare, and show us, a complete example, as minimal as possible, that produce the error.

Answer (score 1):

> Your comparison doesn't satisfy the requirements for std::sort ({0,0,1} and {1,0,0} will both be "greater" than the other). This makes your code undefined. – molbdnilo

This is the reason for the error. Thank you molbdino.